# Windows explorer "open with" custom powershell script

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-explorer

My goal is to be able to right click a file, say `"C:\Users\My PC\folder\file.md"`, select my custom script under the "open with" option, and execute the file with said script.

By 'execute' I mean something like this:

```
# Somehow capture the file path under a variable
$FilePath = ???

# and open it with some terminal program, such as
nvim $FilePath
# or even a non-terminal program, such as
zathura $FilePath
```

*Note: The answer doesn't have to stick with the literal `Open With` option. Any similar option (including from a third party app) that will allow to right click a file and select a script that will use that file path also suffices.*

Comment: This is not how 'Open With' works. `Open With` is not a file dialog, it's an app launch one. `There are many samples all over the web of how to set up 'Open With x app' and 'SendTo some app' to run whatever app/code you choose. You right-click a file to open with an app, not the other way around. What did you search for? What did you try? what happened? Show your work.

Comment: @postanote "You right-click a file to open with an app". Yes, which is exactly what I asked, to right click a file, and 'open with' an app. Just happens that the 'app' is my script. But if some random `exe` can retrieve the file location for use, surely my `ps1` script also can, right? no? I don't know, that's the point of my question

Comment: @postanote and in regards to "what did you search", a lot, found nothing (unless you want me to post all of the google prompts I used). "What did you try?" Nothing. _I don't know what to try_, that's the point. If you don't know how to answer, it's fine, but please don't assume lack of work on my question just cuz. If you have some reference, link them, cuz i've found none.

Comment: @postanote Also note that 'Open With x app' doesn't exactly solve my question. I don't quite want to execute with an `exe`, but with a `ps1`.

Comment: @postanote questions are standard questions that we ask here on this site.  Unlike your response seems to assume, they were not an attack.  As far a your question, I am unaware of any pre-packaged solution that can do this.  I could write myself a file extension in c++ to do it.  A shell extension is the only way to come up with menu options "on the fly" without having them already hard-coded into the windows registry.  This is assuming that I understood the question well enough in the first place.

Comment: You "used  to" be able to put folders in "SendTo" and have anything you wanted in them.  This (with a little creativity) could have solved this but alas.. Microsoft thought this feature was unimportant.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas Yep, I think you did understand correctly. Indeed, I think hard coding _each script_ as a singular option is... suboptimal. But, if that's the only way, I think it might be an acceptable solution.

Comment: (Specially @w32sh's solution, which separates by filetype, reducing the possible mess a lot. If it works in my setup, I'll most likely accept it)

Comment: If w32sh answer works for you, I did not understand the question.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas My perfect solution would be: You right click the file, select some form of "open with script..." option, the file selector opens (same one for when you click on "Save As..." in most programs), you find your script, select it, and it executes with the file path. The suboptimal but acceptable solution from w32sh is: You hard code option in the registry for each script (say, `ex1.ps1`, `ex2.ps1`, and `ex3.ps1`), then you right click the file, and select your script there (say, "open with ex1"). Not perfect... but good enough if you only have a few scripts.

Comment: Probably not usable if you have a lot of scripts though (as you'll end up with a _lot_ of clutter in you right click), so... maybe there's still a better answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This REG file can be used as a template for adding the right-click menu option.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\.md\shell\myscript]
@="Open with PS Script"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\.md\shell\myscript\command]
@="powershell.exe -File \"d:\\scripts\\launch.ps1\" \"%1\""
```

1. Copy the above to Notepad.
2. Save the file as `md.reg`.
3. Double-click  `md.reg` and click Yes when asked for confirmation.
4. Right-click on a .md file, and you'll see the "Open with PS Script"
   option.

Modify the PS command-line arguments as required -- e.g., if your script uses named arguments, add the argument name accordingly in the command-line.

---

### **Option 2: Adding multiple items as a cascading menu**

Here's a template REG file.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\.md\shell\Open with PS]
"Position"="Middle"
"Icon"="PowerShell.exe"
"SubCommands"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\.md\shell\Open with PS\shell]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\.md\shell\Open with PS\shell\01subcmd]
"Icon"="PowerShell.exe"
"MUIVerb"="Open with Script 1"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\.md\shell\Open with PS\shell\01subcmd\command]
@="powershell.exe -File \"d:\\scripts\\launch_1.ps1\" \"%L\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\.md\shell\Open with PS\shell\02subcmd]
"MUIVerb"="Open with Script 2"
"Icon"="PowerShell.exe"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\.md\shell\Open with PS\shell\02subcmd\command]
@="powershell.exe -File \"d:\\scripts\\launch_2.ps1\" \"%L\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\.md\shell\Open with PS\shell\03subcmd]
"MUIVerb"="Open with Script 3"
"Icon"="PowerShell.exe"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\.md\shell\Open with PS\shell\03subcmd\command]
@="powershell.exe -File \"d:\\scripts\\launch_3.ps1\" \"%L\""
```

You get this:

[image]

More about Cascading menus:

1. [How to Create Cascading Menus with the SubCommands Registry Entry
   (Windows) | Microsoft
   Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/hh127467(v=vs.85)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)
2. [Create Cascading Menus with the ExtendedSubCommandsKey Registry
   Entry - Win32 apps | Microsoft
   Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/how-to-create-cascading-menus-with-the-extendedsubcommandskey-registry-entry)
3. [Example: Adding a Cascading menu
   option](https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/open-url-shortcuts-different-browsers-right-click-menu/)

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer, this is really close to what I wanted! I have some questions though:

Comment: 1. I'm getting some weird behaviour when the file path has spaces. For example, the command `wt powershell.exe -NoExit -Command "echo 'C:\Users\luizh\My Drive\Shared\Auto Tuner\documents\Market Analysis.md'"` correctly echoes `C:\Users\luizh\My Drive\Shared\Auto Tuner\documents\Market Analysis.md`. However, using the registry command `wt powershell.exe -NoExit -Command "echo '%1'"` incorrectly echoes `C:\Users\luizh\MYDRIV~1\Shared\AUTOTU~1\DOCUME~1\MARKET~1.MD`. Do you know why?

Comment: 2. If you have more than one script (say 5 or 10) that might end cluttering the right click. Is there a way to "collapse" them into a tab? (similar to the "Open with", or "Give access to", or "Send to" options)

Comment: It seems to echo the file name in SFN format. I can't repro the issue. However, you can try replacing `%1` with `%L` to see if that fixes the problem. Regarding the cascading menu, it can surely be done. How many items are you going to add?

Comment: I've edited my response to include the cascading menu template REG file.

Answer (score 0):

May be worth shouting out [OpenWithPlusPlus](https://github.com/stax76/OpenWithPlusPlus), which is a GUI alternative to @w32sh's answer, where you can create the same type of "Open with..." menu in a simple to use GUI interface. Nice thing for one-offs.

If you want to automate this process though, I'd still recommend going with a `.reg` or `.ps1` file for changing the registry.